# Javascript count up onload load function

Tags: javascript, count, load, onload, effect

I am creating a script which will refresh "viewers" count displayed at the top of my website.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#viewers').load('viewers.php');
}, 5000);
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<span id="viewers">0</span>
```

viewers.php output:

```
100
```

I'd like to add a "count up/down" effect, so for example if the viewers.php outputs 200, it will then count up after the 5000 milliseconds, and if this count dropped to 50, the 100 will count down to 50.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You want it to count from the current viewers # to the number given by viewers.php over the span of 5000 ms?

Comment: What is in viewers.php?

Comment: Correct! Counting with a duration of 4 seconds. The 500ms is just the amount of time it takes between refreshing the state.

Comment: Adam, it's connected to the database which for now is just echoing a number value.

Comment: The question is very confusing as written. Please [edit] to provide more detail and clear explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that counts up or down to the new number of viewers over a given delay period.  It seems to run a little slow, probably due to the delay of my code inside the setInterval.

Just call the `setViewers` whenever you want to update the count.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){


var delay = 4000;
var viewers = $("#viewers");
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
  var curViewers = Number(viewers.html())
  $('#viewers').load('viewers.php', function(){
    var newViewers = Number(viewers.html());
    setViewers(curViewers, newViewers);
  });

}, 5000);



function setViewers(currentNum, newNum){
  if(currentNum == newNum) return;
  var updateSpeed = delay / Math.abs(currentNum - newNum);
  var countDir = currentNum > newNum ? -1 : 1;
  var timer = setInterval(function(){    
    currentNum += countDir;
    viewers.text(currentNum);
    if(currentNum == newNum) clearInterval(timer);
  }, updateSpeed);
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I'm having some trouble linking it up with the `load('viewers.php')` part. How could I grab the `currentNum` from the div and grab the `newNum` from the load function, to then call it?

Comment: I'm honestly not very familiar with php or jquery's `load` but I edited in a possible way to call my code.  Haven't tested it so it might not be quite right yet.